# Is it possible to test cross platform mobile application with Appium C#?

Tags: c#, android, ios, appium, ui-automation

We have one application that is developed using **Xamarin** cross platform development tool. This app has same interface for ios(ipa) and android(apk). Can we write one automation script and run it across both the platforms i.e both for android and ios app.

Currently,we are using **Xamarin UiTest** to test cross platform application with same code base i.e both for android and ios app, but it has some limitation like app context switching is not possible in **Xamarin UiTest**. Here, we want to use **Appium**  with C# to overcome this limitation (other limitation also) of **Xamarin UiTest**. Is it possible to test cross platform mobile application with *Appium C# client*?

Comment: i got the solution of this problem. I will share that solution if someone need it.

Comment: Link for the same: https://github.com/VikashChauhan51/AppiumCore